# How to connect my remote server on csgo

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting, server-administration

I rent virtual machine and I applied instructions which is written [here](http://gameservermanagers.com/lgsm/csgoserver/) in order to create my own csgo server. Everything is OK, but i cannot connect my server typing public ip address. Is it normal? What should I do?  I googled, and found some information like +net_public_adr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx or +ip 0.0.0.0 but im not sure how can I use them, or should I use them?

[image]

Comment: Have you port forwarded it?

Comment: @Frank how to check my port? I tried to type `sudo ufw status` and I saw these information. Is it OK? [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JoomL.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JoomL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your server won't be up untill you add a token to it. [Here](http://dathost.net/blog/how-to-create-and-use-gameserver-login-tokens-gslts-for-your-dedicated-csgo-server/) is how to create it.